# Concatenate list elements that fall between list elements of certain value

Tags: python, list, split

Imagine I have the following list:

```
>>> mylist

[('a', u'DT'),
 ('Satisfactory', u'JJ'),
 ('tracing', u'VBG'),
 ('with', u'IN'),
 ('a', u'DT'),
 ('fairly', u'RB'),
 ('persistent', u'JJ'),
 ('with', u'IN')]
```

How do I concatenate list items that fall between elements that contain `u'IN'` or `u'DT'` and return only the concatenated elements i.e:

```
[('Satisfactory tracing'),
 ('fairly persistent')]
```

Comment: @engr_s It's the second element of the result: `('fairly persistent')`

Comment: Try using itertools.dropwhile() and itertools.takewhile().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one which shall give you the desired result. Maybe you need to optimize it a bit.

```
my_list = ([('a', u'DT'),
            ('Satisfactory', u'JJ'),
            ('tracing', u'VBG'),
            ('with', u'IN'),
            ('a', u'DT'),
            ('fairly', u'RB'),
            ('persistent', u'JJ'),
            ('with', u'IN')])

sequence_enable = False
new_list = []
for i in my_list:
    if i[1] == 'DT' or i[1] == 'IN':
        if not sequence_enable: # Start reading values 
            sequence_enable = True
            temp_str = []
        else: # stop reading values
            new_list.append(' '.join(temp_str)) 
            sequence_enable = False

        continue
    else: # store values
        if sequence_enable:
            temp_str.append(i[0])

print(new_list)
# output: ['Satisfactory tracing', 'fairly persistent']
```

Comment: fantastic - works for me and can easy to add in new split tags. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution:

```
idt = [item for item in range(len(mylist)) if mylist[item][1] == u'DT']
jdt = [item for item in range(len(mylist)) if mylist[item][1] == u'IN']

ij = zip(idt,jdt)

temp_list = [mylist[i[0]+1:i[1]] for i in ij]

new_list = [str(elem[0][0]+ ' ' + elem[1][0]) for elem in temp_list]
```

It first finds the indices of `u'DT'` and `u'IN'` in `mylist`, then it zips them together into a list of tuples, `ij`. Each tuple is the beginning and end of the interval from which the program is supposed to extract values. The values are first extracted as they appear in `mylist` into `temp_list`. Last step forms the target `new_list` that joins and processes extracted values stored in `temp_list`.

This solution does not give you values within brackets `( )` - it seems that to achieve this, elements of `new_list` would either have to be turned into tuples, i.e. `('Satisfactory tracing',)` or the bracket would have to be part of the string `'(Satisfactory tracing)'`.

Edit - solution for any number of strings between `DT` and `IN` - everything until `new_list` is the same, `new_list` is formed by extracting first element from each element in the sublist of `temp_list` and joining them into one string,

```
new_list = [((' ').join(map(lambda x: x[0], sub_el))) for sub_el in temp_list]
```

Testing with

```
mylist = [('a', u'DT'), ('Satisfactory', u'JJ'), ('Satisfactory', u'JJ'), 
('tracing', u'VBG'),('with', u'IN'),('a', u'DT'),('fairly', u'RB'),
('persistent', u'JJ'),('with', u'IN'), ('a', u'DT'),('persistent', u'JJ'),
('with', u'IN')]
```

yields

```
['Satisfactory Satisfactory tracing', 'fairly persistent', 'persistent']
```

Comment: thanks for this. The last command to create new_list complains about list index being out of range. I think this is because `temp_list` contains mostly empty elements. I can see that you wanted `temp_list` to pick up elements asis from `mylist` but this hasn't happened and I think this causes the error.

Comment: Glad to help. There was no error for me - all this was checked with the exact example that you provided. Can you post the example that causes the error? Also `temp_list` is not empty at all.

Comment: I guess this will only be valid when there are two elements between `DT` and `IN`.

Comment: Edited - now it can handle any number of strings between `DT` and `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code and real code:

```
while elements remain in mylist:
    # Find the next "DT" element
    look at next element
    while element[1] is not "DT":
        look at next element

    # Watch for "IN"; concatenate elements in the meantime.
    result = []
    look at next element
    while element[1] is not "IN":
        result.append(element[0])

    # result is a list of the words you want
    result_conc = ' '.join(result)
```

Does that get you moving?