# Extracting multiple piece of data in a list between keywords

Tags: python

This code extracts the data (1, 2, 3) between the key words 'start' and 'end'

```
some_data = ['a', 2, 'b', 'start', 1, 2, 3, 'end']

start = some_data.index('start')+1
end = some_data.index('end')

for data in some_data[start:end]:
     print(data)
```

but what happens if there is multiple pieces of data in the list among lines of rubbish like:

```
['a', 2, 'b', 'start', 1, 2, 3, 'end', 'a', 1, x, 'start', 3,  7, 8, 'end', 'start', 3, 7, 8, 'end']
```

how can you get extract them all instead of just the first piece of data

Comment: Try iterating over the list in a loop.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819586/concatenate-list-elements-that-fall-between-list-elements-of-certain-value/46820133#46820133) from the other day may give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenter above, here's a very simple example of what could be done.

```
some_data = ['a', 2, 'b', 'start', 1, 2, 3, 'end', 'a', 1, 'x', 'start', 3,  7, 8, 'end', 'start', 3, 7, 8, 'end']

index = 0
retrieved_data = []
while index < len(some_data):
    if some_data[index] == 'start':
        collecting = True
        values = []
        while collecting:
            index += 1
            if some_data[index] == 'end':
                collecting = False
            else:
                values.append(some_data[index])
        retrieved_data.append(values)
    index += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Woul;d it easy to edit this so each [piece of data is added to its own tuple or a seprate list

Comment: Do you mean to have different tuples/lists for each interval between the 'start' and 'end' signal words? I can edit it to reflect this change.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to get the index numbers of the items and use them how you want to:

```
def get_indexes(items, keyword):
    indexes = []
    if keyword in items:
        for i, data in enumerate(items):
            if data == keyword:
                indexes.append(i)
    else:
        raise AttributeError("invalid keyword given")
    return indexes
```

This will return a `list` of all the indexes with the specified keyword:

```
some_data = ['a', 2, 'b', 'start', 1, 2, 3, 'end', 'a', 1, 'x', 'start', 3,  7, 8, 'end', 'start', 3, 7, 8, 'end']
get_indexes(some_data, "start")
# [3, 11, 16]
get_indexes(some_data, "end")
# [7, 15, 20]
```

Answer (score -1):

The "pythonic" way to do this is simple iteration over list without dealing with indexes. Here's an example of how it could be done:

```
def get_intervals(data):
    collecting = False
    intervals = []

    for item in data:
        if item == 'start':
            interval = []
            collecting = True
            continue
        if item == 'end':
            intervals.append(interval)
            collecting = False
            continue
        if collecting:
            interval.append(item)

    return intervals
```